# Redmine Plugin Installation error

Tags: linux, redmine-plugins

I'm new in Linux so sorry for a rookie questions. 
I deployed the Redcase 1.0 zip and unziped it on: 
/opt/redmine-3.0.3-0/apps/redmine/htdocs/plugins/
The plugin appears on the Redcase "Plugin" page. But the "Test Case" doesn't appear on the project information tab.
I tried to run the migrate command but received an error:
I think I'm running that command from a wrong path. You say to run it from #{RAILS_ROOT}. Where exactly this path?

```
[root@ALM001 bin]# bash bundle exec rake redmine:plugins:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
bundle: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bundle: line 2: `ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../../Gemfile', __FILE__)'
```

So bash doesn't fit, right?

Supposing that my Rails_Env is "/opt/redmine-3.0.3-0/apps/redmine/htdocs/" I run

```
"[root@ALM001 htdocs]# bundle exec rake redmine:plugins:migrate RAILS_ENV=production"
```

and receive an error:

```
-bash: bundle: command not found
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, I figured out that I'm missing rubby and bundle installations, so I installed gems and bundle.
Now, I receive the following error:

[root@ALM001 htdocs]# bundle exec rake redmine:plugins:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
bundler: command not found: rake
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`

Comment: *** Update ***
After restarting the Redmine, Apache refuses to start with ad error:
Message from application: cannot load such file -- rack (LoadError)
  /opt/redmine-3.0.3-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-5.0.6/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:106:in `require'